# If I buy a Fifa 15 disk, do I need it every time I play on PC?

Tags: fifa-15

I want to get Fifa 15, but I don't want to have to look after a disk. The digital download straight from Origin is significantly more expensive than a physical copy from third party retailers so I'd rather not get that. I understand that Fifa 15 on PC uses Origin for physical copies anyway, so can I just buy the cheaper disk, install, register with Origin and then throw my disk away?

Answer (score 2):

Well not throw away, but your basically right!  I purchased an Origin game activated the serial from my account and the game does not require a disc anymore.

*1) Buy game disc*

*2) Activate serial on Origin store*

*3) Install game from disc to PC*

*4) Login onto Origin*

*5) Play without disc*

---

This is personal knowledge and experience no references.

Comment: Was the game you bought FIFA 15 though?

Comment: I did this with Battle Field 4, Dragon Age, Sims 4, and a few others.

Comment: Assuming this is the same for Fifa, would I be able to reinstall the game without the disk?

Comment: Certainly once the game is linked to your account you can download it from origin.